# Synology shared folder created from other synology rsync: authorization, permissions access denied

Tags: permissions, rsync, synology

I set up a synology rsync from an old NAS (DSM 6.15) to a new one (DSM 7.2). (in synology DSM : shared folder sync ("synchro du dossier partagé" in French).)

When you do so, the task creates the new shared folder on the new NAS, but authorizations on this new shared folder are all forbidden.

See solution bellow...

Answer (score 0):

Go to new nas settings: shared folder: : modify: Advanced shared folder permissions: Activate advanced permissions: advanced permissions:

There you should find a group named "administrators" with read access only. Unselect it, then you could also unselect "activate advance permissions".

Then you should be able to manage users permissions on shared folder (through local groups or users or through some LDAP for instance).

Kind regards.